# Python Plotting Using Class

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to define a class point(x,y) that represents a point in a Euclidean plane, which I completed with:

```
class point():
    def __init__(P,x,y):
        P.x=x
        P.y=y
```

Now I must extend this class by creating methods that will:

1. Return a point A that is a vertical reflection of P across the horizontal line at y using `A=P.verticalReflect(y)`.
2. Return a point B that translates the point P a distance of x in the x-direction and a distance of y in the y-direction using `B=P.translate(x,y)`.
3. Display a point using pyplot using `P.display(options)`. I should be able to let the user print a label, set the font size and offset from the point.

An example of code that will initiate the class created would be:

```
P=point(2,3)
P.display(label="P",labeloffset=0.2)

A=P.verticalReflect(y=3.5)
A.display(c="green",label="A",labeloffset=0.1)
plt.axhline(y=3.5,c="k",ls="--")
```

I'm having trouble figuring out where to start to define these new methods in the class.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it is conventional to capitalize class names, so `class Point` instead of `class point`, and also, it is conventional to use `self` as the first argument to a method definition.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

You should define these methods within the class scope, not really important where and in which order. What follows is a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def verticalReflect(self,y):
        # your code. an example would be
        dy = y - self.y
        self.y += 2*dy
        return Point(self.x,self.y)

    def translate(self,x,y):
        self.x += x
        self.y += y
        return Point(self.x,self.y)

    def display(self,<options_here>):
        # your code. an example would be
        plt.plot(self.x,self.y,'o',<handle_options>)
        #plt.show()

plt.hold(True)
plt.axis([-10,10,-10,10])
p = Point(2,2)
p.display()
p.translate(3,-1)
p.display()
p.verticalReflect(3)
p.display() 
p.verticalReflect(2)
p.display()
plt.show()
```

If you omit the `<options_here>` and `<handle_options>` parts you have a working example of how to do it. Mind that you can plot and show points immediately within `display()` method if you uncomment `plt.show()` call.

I set it up like so, that you call `plt.hold(True)` first and plot all points on the canvas first, and show all at once only in the last line of code.

I also added the `return Point(self.x,self.y)` to your code, so you can create new point instead of changing the existing one. If you want to keep the starting point intact you should change `self.x|y += ...` to `x|y += ...` and return `return Point(x,y)`.

Best of luck!

Comment: I do not think `hold` does what you think it does.  If is `hold` is `False` many of the plotting methods will have an implicit `cla` in them.